# Base64 Encoded in AspNetCore Api Route

Tags: asp.net-core, base64, asp.net-core-mvc, urlencode, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating a [OCSP Responder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) following the rules as defined in [RFC 6960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960).

So, I need to implement a **GET** service whose route MUST be:

```
{url}/{url-encoding of base-64 encoding of the DER encoding of the OCSPRequest}
```

I created my GET action:

```
[Route("api/ocsp")]
public class OcspController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{encoded}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string encoded)
    {
        var ocspHttpRequest = await Request.ToOcspHttpRequest();
        var ocspHttpResponse =  await OcspResponder.Respond(ocspHttpRequest);
        return new OcspActionResult(ocspHttpResponse);
    }
    ...
 }
```

However, ASP.NET Core doesn't find or returns a Bad Request for the route when the URL is encoded, which is necessary.

Ocsp request in base64 (note it have two lines):

```
MEkwRzBFMEMwQTAJBgUrDgMCGgUABBR1vr6HF4T/UsADPXoNr6lpJ1JRowQUJfgJ
6MaP2huu1lFzJOFlkswOcM8CCB6PD3SWpxwf
```

Url encode of base64 ocsp request:

```
MEkwRzBFMEMwQTAJBgUrDgMCGgUABBR1vr6HF4T%2FUsADPXoNr6lpJ1JRowQUJfgJ%0A6MaP2huu1lFzJOFlkswOcM8CCB6PD3SWpxwf
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Certain characters that result from Base64 encoding are invalid in the URL path. This can be changed, but it's set that way for a reason: namely for security. If you allow those characters, you're opening yourself up to a number of attacks that wouldn't be possible otherwise.

However, you're free to pass it as part of the *query string*. You won't get errors when handled that way.

Comment: Can it be changed for a specific Action? How to change this? I think I cannot use querystring because of the RFC specification.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround, you could change {encoded} to {*encoded}, then it will accept not allowed otherwise symbols.